# JavaScript NaN equvialence

Tags: javascript, nan

Just for fun I was trying to compare a value which I set to NaN to another value which I also set to NaN.

Why are two variables, with identical values, not equivalent?

```
var a = Number.Nan
var b = Number.Nan
a === b
false

a == b
false

var a = NaN
var b = NaN
a === b 
false
a == b
false
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: NaN is not equal to anything including NaN itself. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6

Comment: Note: Going forward (ES6+ or [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Browser_compatibility)), you'll be able to compare `NaN` values using [`Object.is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is).

Comment: Even weirder, `a == a` returns false :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NaN is Not a Number, there is no evaluated numberic value to compare - Use IsNaN() To compare NaN values. [W3 Schools link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp)

Answer (score 2):

As @TechnicalChaos said, but here are links to MDN over W3Schools ;)

NaN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

IsNaN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

The pertinent parts being:

> It is rather rare to use NaN in a program. It is the returned value
>   when Math functions fail (Math.sqrt(-1)) or when a function trying to
>   parse a number fails (parseInt("blabla")).

And:

> Unlike all other possible values in JavaScript, it is not possible to
>   rely on the equality operators (== and ===) to determine whether a
>   value is NaN or not, because both NaN == NaN and NaN === NaN evaluate
>   to false. Hence, the necessity of an isNaN function.

Don't think of `NaN` along the same lines as `null` or `undefined`, it's a "special case" :P

But if you're willing to risk it for a biscuit:

```
NaN.toString() === NaN.toString()
true
```

But don't do that!

Comment: Thanks for padding out the answer, :) I did feel a little lazy but i've been helping another feller out over on another post.

Comment: Just doing some idle reading on this after the question and came to a good article that goes into this quite well. Thought you both may enjoy the read. 

[Truth, equality and Javascript](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-jTrutavascript/)

Comment: Wonky link. This one? https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Comment: Bah failed copypaste sorry! Yeah thats the one :)

Comment: JS crazies: http://wtfjs.com/

Comment: Here's the one I was looking for: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: Heh yeah I've watched that talk :) Which tells me amongst other things that I need a hobby.

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind that a lot of JavaScript isn't great. It was designed in 10 days and a lot (not all) of it may not be intuitive. This is one of those times where you don't think about why and you just use isNaN(someVar) to check for it.

Comment: This isn't a Javascript ideosynchracy, it's part of the IEEE standard for floating point.

Comment: If Brian has said "Keep in mind that some of JavaScript is weird", I'd agree: `{} + {} // NaN`, `[] + []; // ""` and the best one `[] + {}; // [object Object]` :P